# How to get last id in dataframe with object id?

Tags: python, pandas, rest

Using cm commerce api, I pull some data and upload (write_append) it to the big query. However, the unique id in the incoming data(from cm commerce API) looks like this:

```
id                          title       liveAt                      sentAt
615eb5eba59a60002e6c5c6e    news        2021-09-13T06:00:00.000Z    2021-09-13T12:21:09.122Z
615eb5eba59a60002e6c5c6e    table       2021-09-15T06:00:00.000Z    2021-09-17T12:21:09.122Z
6158c7a59a110600346495aa    lists       2021-09-11T07:00:00.000Z    2021-09-12T07:00:00.000Z
```

I need the last id to add the data I pulled from the api to the table in the big query. In this way, I can add new data to the big query from the last row.
The **id** column is not an auto-incrementing integer column, some data is lost when I use it. What happens if I get the **liveAt** column as the last id and there are two rows with the same date ?

I created an id column with this code:

`df.insert(0, 'New_ID', range(0 + len(df)))`

but I couldn't find how to bind it with the new data from the api.
how can i deal with this problem ?

Comment: Hi, so, if I understand you well, you're trying to create a new "id" column with unique ids in it (which is note the case of your current "id" column)?

Comment: I'm getting the latest date as the last id. I've been updating this way for about a month and I haven't had any problems. So i use liveAt column instead of id column.